# Segfault with recursive function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int recursive(int f,int g){
    static int a;;
    static int b;
    int c = 100;
    a = f;
    b = g;
    if(c != 105){
        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
        recursive(a,b);
    }

    printf("\n a : %d b : %d \n",a,b);

    return 0;
}


int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1;
    recursive(a,b);
}
```

The above example recursive program gives a segfault. Couldn't understand why the segfault happens as there is no pointers involved.

Comment: Where is base case for your recursive function ?

Comment: Its an infinte loop...

Comment: "Couldn't understand why the segfault happens as there is no pointers involved." - that... that... that... is just nonsense.

Comment: @haccks it has a base case, returning 0, the problem here is C never changes its value.

Comment: 1. You forgot `return 0;` in `main`
2. You got an extra `;` after `static int a;`
3. You have an infinite loop as `c` is not `static`

Comment: @levi; I do not see the use of that return value.

Comment: @levi Nonsense, becuase the if-branch is **always** entered.

Comment: @hacks because he is not using the returning value that does not mean that the recursion dont have a base case.

Comment: @ThreeFx yes I mean that. always entered because C is always 100.

Comment: at least here you're at the right address

Comment: Pass the 'c' in as parameter too.

Comment: Why are you so fixated on statics?  They are not necessary and are actively harmful in multithreaded code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `c` variable is not static, you will call `recursive` again and again, always reinitializing it with `100`, so your program will never stop and will eventually crash due to a stack overflow. I suppose you meant `c` to increment each time the function is called recursively? Then you need to change its declaration:

```
static int c = 100;
```

(That's what several others have mentioned: "you need a base case", and you'd get it if `c` is static.)

But in this case, it will never again be set to 100, so you will get to use your function with your (probable) intended behavior only once.

Answer (score 11):

You have infinite recursion in there. Because `c` is *never* equal to `105` (it's set to `100` every time you enter the function), the function will simply keep calling itself over and over, until you blow up the stack (exceed its capacity).

It boils down to something as simple as:

```
int blowUpStack (int a) {
    blowUpStack (a);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The cause of the segfault is stack overflow :).

Stack is filling by function return adresses and local stacks until main stack pointer reach bound of stack segment.

Comment: you answer = flawless victory.

Answer (score 7):

Your variable c will never be greater than 101, each time the function is called it gets reset to 100, and then incremented once.

Answer (score 7):

Segfaults don't only happen with pointers. In that case, you have infinite recursion, and the segfault is your function call stack munching through your addressable memory, until it bites some that isn't yours. Boom.

As for the why, here's a clue : `c` is a different variable in each function call, so merely incrementing it has no effect on the next ones.

Answer (score 3):

Seg Fault occurs usually when you try to access any memory address that is not allocated to you. It does not depend on whether you use pointers or not.

In this question, your recursion never ends because there is no base case in the function to exit. Therefore, infinite recursive calls will lead to stack overflow and hence your program may access an unallocated memory address.

In this case you may want `c` to hold its value in previous call, hence you need to declare it `static`.

Comment: @MartinJames: Good point, but that can be explained to the OP if he ask for it after trying to implement that and finding some problem. Explaining him now won't be required.